# Django page URL contains %3f instead of "?" sign

Tags: django, url, redirect

I'm using Django paginator in CBV, and after form submit (creates new post) I'm trying to redirect to actual page with newly created post. I'm using `reverse_lazy` with keyword argument for page number, but in URL generated with `reverse_lazy`, `?` sign on the beginning is changed to `%3F`, e.g. `?page=7`->`%3Fpage=7`. And consequently, I get redirected to first page.

My URL path:

```
path("homeT/?page=<int:num>", views.homeTestView.as_view(), name="actual_page"),
```

I use `reverse_lazy` like this:

```
return reverse_lazy("actual_page", kwargs={'num': page_num})
```

P.S. And is there a easier way to get redirect to page with newly created post/comment?? Thank you.

Comment: Query arguments are not part of the URL

Comment: page_num is not a query argument here. There can be any number instead of page_num variable, and still I will get %3F instead of "?" mark in generated URL.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance. Yes, page_num is a query argument, which is not part of the URL by accessed via the `requwst.GET` querydict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i solved this with using such "hardcoded" approach: 
`return reverse("homeT") + "?page=%s" % page_num.` 
And redirect to page with newly created post is described
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48094538/10014728)